# CPQ - Template Section - Group Field - Sorting

Tags: cpq, group-by, template, quote-template

I am in the process of using the Group Field in the Template Section object to Group a Line Items section, and am hitting an issue.

It seems to be grouping in alphabetical order of the picklist values eg "Add-On" appears before "Bundle".  Is there a way to configure which order the groups appear?  ie "Bundle" to appear before "Add-On"

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to have another picklist field . It will have the same picklist values, but in the order that you want. Then populate the data from the original field to the new.

This is assuming you can't just reorder the values in the original picklist field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to have a formula field that makes them alphabetical in the order you want to use for grouping. Then you can customize the label for the grouping, using this trick: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_group_items_templates.htm&type=5

> Salesforce CPQ can set the heading label for your grouping based off a
>   different field than you use for the rest of your grouped line items.
>   Create a group label field on the Quote Line object using a naming
>   convention of [field name]Label__c. For example, if the API name of
>   your Group Field is "Required__c," the label field for it would be
>   called "RequiredLabel__c".